# How do you write unit tests that involve databases?

Tags: unit-testing, node.js

In Node.js, I wrote a twitter client. How can I write unit tests that involve people posting threads and stuff?

Answer (score 6):

In a word, stubs. When unit testing, write stub functions for your Twitter API calls that simply return the same data and responses each time. You're not testing Twitter's API, after all.

Comment: Depending what the database code does, a SQLite database in memory is also great for unit tests.

Answer (score 3):

When you write your tests first(TDD) it becomes more naturally to do something called [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Manually_injected_dependency). Uncle Bob practices [three rules](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheThreeRulesOfTdd) when doing TDD:

> Over the years I have come to describe
>   Test Driven Development in terms of
>   three simple rules. They are: You are
>   not allowed to write any production
>   code unless it is to make a failing
>   unit test pass. You are not allowed to
>   write any more of a unit test than is
>   sufficient to fail; and compilation
>   failures are failures. You are not
>   allowed to write any more production
>   code than is sufficient to pass the
>   one failing unit test.
>
> You must begin by writing a unit test
>   for the functionality that you intend
>   to write. But by rule 2, you can't
>   write very much of that unit test. As
>   soon as the unit test code fails to
>   compile, or fails an assertion, you
>   must stop and write production code.
>   But by rule 3 you can only write the
>   production code that makes the test
>   compile or pass, and no more.
>
> If you think about this you will
>   realize that you simply cannot write
>   very much code at all without
>   compiling and executing something.
>   Indeed, this is really the point. In
>   everything we do, whether writing
>   tests, writing production code, or
>   refactoring, we keep the system
>   executing at all times. The time
>   between running tests is on the order
>   of seconds, or minutes. Even 10
>   minutes is too long.

You can also do stubbing with I think some popular stubbing-frameworks:

- https://github.com/felixge/node-gently
- https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#testing

Comment: That link is now deprecated.